# Accessing Substitution Strings with SSJS in Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, automationstudio

I'm trying to drop a file into a particular FTP folder, and run a script that needs to access the file name. I know that `%%BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%` can give you the file name minus the extension, but so far I'm not having any luck calling that variable value into SSJS.

File name sample: `File_Name-Second.txt`

I've tried a few things:

```
var uploadedFileName = Platform.Variable.GetAttributeValue('BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER').split('-');
```

I've also tried

```
var uploadedFileName = Variable.GetValue('BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER').split('-');
```

It's a tough thing to test because you just have to set off the trigger and then wait, and I'm not able to locate any details in the activity page. I just get an email that says "it didn't work."

(The split is to fill other variables with values from uploadFileName[0] and [1].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible, as far as I know.

The trigger [**substitution strings**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/triggered_automations/#FilenamePatterns) -- cue air quote hand motions -- are really just filename patterns that are limited to triggered automations.

Generally speaking, other [**substitution/personalization strings**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/) are scoped to info from an email send and the recipient.

Comment: I was working off of this page: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/triggered_automations/

I just saw these strings are only available for file transfer activity or import activity. Which is a shame, because in my particular case it'd be really useful to use them in a script; part of the automation process.

Comment: Did you ever find a work around for this issue?  I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: Seconded - also looking to use the filename in a script.

Comment: What I wound up doing was dropping a CSV onto the FTP server that imported into a "holding tank" data extension, in which the name of the file in question was in one of the fields. My script retrieved that field value from the DE, and then continued with the rest of the process.